# Background fetch not working on physical device

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, background, fetch

I have following problem:
I made a chat app which is using background fetch to update the data and receive notifications. Everything is working fine if I´m simulating the background fetch via Xcode, but if i want to use the app without Xcode (in the simulator or on a real physical device) it won´t execute the background fetch. I set the Minimum background fetch time to `UIApplication.backgroundFetchIntervalMinimum` and tried to enable "launch due to a background fetch event", and archive the app and install it manually (background fetch with Run/Archive not working).
Anybody have an idea?

Thanks for help!

Comment: Background fetch probably isn't a good solution for a chat app. It can take several days before background fetch starts working for a new app, and even then it is only invoked every hour or two. You should probably be using remote notifications from your server.

Comment: @Paulw11 Thanks! I'll use remote notifications.

Comment: You need VOIP notifications for chat app